# How to perform on-submit form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I want to replace the after-submission checks in the form with on-the-fly completeness and correctness checks that are performed when a form field loses focus.

How can I do this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <style>
body {    
  width: 500px;
}
.part {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.label-left {
  text-align: right;
}
.label-right {
  text-align: left;
}
.error {
  color: #cc0000;
}
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      //$(document).ready(function() {

 function myValidateEMailAddress(email_address) {
     
     var email_pattern = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
     return email_pattern.test(email_address);
  }
  
  function checkPassword(pwd_str) {
   var my_pwd_pattern = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,20}$/;
   return my_pwd_pattern.test(pwd_str);
}
function validatePhoneNumber(phone_number) {
     
     var phone_pattern = /^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$/;
     return phone_pattern.test(phone_number);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
      var my_errors = false;
      $('.part> .error').remove();
      $('#my_submission').empty();
      $(':text, :password, textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
           $(this).parent().append('<div class="error">Please provide a value</div>');
           my_errors = true;
        }
      });
      if ($('#email').val() != '') {
         if (!myValidateEMailAddress($('#email').val())) {
            $('#email').parent().append('<div class="error">Please provide a correct e-mail address</div>');
            my_errors = true;
         }
      }
   if ($('#your_password').val() != '') {
         if (!checkPassword($('#your_password').val())) {
            $('#your_password').parent().append('<div class="error">Please provide a correct password.</div>');
            my_errors = true;
         }
      }
    if ($('#phone').val() != '') {
         if (!validatePhoneNumber($('#phone').val())) {
            $('#phone').parent().append('<div class="error">Please provide a correct phone number.</div>');
            my_errors = true;
         }
      }
      if ($('#addresses option:selected').val() == '') {
         $('#addresses').parent().append('<div class="error">Please select one item</div>');
         my_errors = true;
      }
   if ($(':radio[name="sex"]:checked').length == 0) {
         $(':radio[name="sex"]:first').parent().after('<div class="error">Please select one item</div>');
         my_errors = true;
      }
   if ($(':radio[name="subscription"]:checked').length == 0) {
         $(':radio[name="subscription"]:first').parent().after('<div class="error">Please select one item</div>');
         my_errors = true;
      }
      if ($('#likes option:selected').val() == '') {
         $('#likes').parent().append('<div class="error">Please select one item</div>');
         my_errors = true;
      }
      if (my_errors) {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         e.preventDefault();
         var my_submission_array = $('#form').serialize().split('&');
         if (my_submission_array.length > 0) {
            $('#my_submission').html('<h2>Submitted Elements</h2><ul></ul>');
            for (var i = 0; i < my_submission_array.length; i++) {
                var my_pair = my_submission_array[i].split('=');
                $('#my_submission > ul').append('<li>' + my_pair[0] + ': ' + my_pair[1] + '</li>\n');
            }
         }
      }
    });
  });

     // });
    </script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Output:</h3>
<h2>My Questionnaire</h2>
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="post">
 <div class="part">
    <label for="addresses" class="label-left">How should you be addressed?</label>
    <select name="addresses" id="addresses">
      <option value="">Please select one</option>
      <option value="first">Mr.</option>
      <option value="second">Madam</option>
      <option value="third">Miss</option>
      <option value="fourth">Dr.</option>
   <option value="fifth">Pr.</option>
    </select>   
  </div>
 
  <div class="part">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Sex:</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="sex" id="group1" value="1">
      <label for="group1" class="label-right">Male</label> 
      <input type="radio" name="sex" id="group2" value="2">
      <label for="group2" class="label-right">Female</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <label for="last_name" class="label-left">Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <label for="first_name" class="label-left">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <label for="email" class="label-left">E-Mail: </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="part"> 
  <label for="your_password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="your_password" id="your_password" size="10" maxlength="20"> 
 </div>
 <div class="part">
    <label for="phone" class="label-left">Phone number: </label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <label for="likes" class="label-left">What are your likes?</label>
    <select name="likes" id="likes">
      <option value="">Please select one</option>
      <option value="first">Programming</option>
      <option value="second"> African literature</option>
      <option value="third">Poetry</option>
      <option value="four">Dancing</option>
    </select>   
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Do you want to receive our newsletter ?</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="subscription" id="group1" value="1">
      <label for="group1" class="label-right">Yes</label> 
      <input type="radio" name="letter" id="group2" value="2">
      <label for="group2" class="label-right">No</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <label for="comments" class="label-left">Write some comments below:</label>
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form">
  </div>
  <div id="my_submission"></div>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried something but the blur does not work for any element and I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I continue answering, I should note that you're putting jQuery script before `<html>` tag. This is incorrect. It has to be in `<head>`

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
```

> performed when a form field loses focus

An element loses focus when you click away from it. jQuery happends to have a `blur` event for this occasion:

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

So you might want to do it this way:

```
$('#email').on('blur', function() {
    var emailVal = $(this).val();
    if (!emailVal || !myValidateEMailAddress(emailVal)) {
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="error">Please provide a correct e-mail address</div>');
        my_errors = true;
    }
});
```

the rest of the code might look similar.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on each of them separately to see how it works individually.